# What parts of a laptop can I upgrade? (other than basic upgrades)

Tags: laptop, upgrade

I bought a Lenovo G570 core i3 I was wondering what parts other than the basic upgrades (i.e. hard drive, ram, video card) can I make. Can I upgrade CPU of a laptop or is it fixed to the motherboard? Can I upgrade things like the WiFi card, monitor, keyboard to back-lit etc.

Comment: With many lenovos, your system won't boot with a wifi card that's not in their whitelist.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the laptop
some have real easy way to replace RAM, HDD/SSD and Wifi, but others dont, (ram soldered to mb etc)
and no you cannot upgrade the CPU (unless you want to change 80% of the laptop), why would you want to?, the cpu is tied to the fans, so if you install a faster cpu, the fans wont keep up and sometimes the chassis is made for that cpu

anyhow i agree with james

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad question, with many answers. Very technically, the limitations of the upgradable items on a laptop are based on your comfortability and expertise.

For the average end-user, purchasing replacement parts and following guides is as far as they're willing to go.

Of course, with the time and resources required to modify the laptop enclosure to accommodate some replacement parts, one might be better served building a custom laptop themselves.